# Redirect unless current_user owns object - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a canvas model and a user model. I only want users to be able to view the canvases edit action if they own the canvas.

So if the user visits the canvases edit action, I want to redirect them to the canvas show action unless they own the canvas.

So far I have this in my canvas controller edit action:

```
unless @canvas.user_id = current_user.id
  redirect_to @canvas
end
```

It doesn't seem to have any effect though. Should I be using a before_filter?

Comment: `=` is assignment.  `==` is equality.

Comment: Answer for the vote :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=` is assignment. `==` is equality.  It's always important to know which one to use when.

Comment: I ran into a problem. If the user is not currently signed in, I'd like them to be able to view the show actions. But if the user is not signed in, there is no current_user, so my code is throwing an error. How would I get around that?

Comment: If you change the unless line to `unless current_user.nil? || @canvas.user_id == current_user.id`, when the first part before the `or` is null, it'll short circuit the second part and go into the redirect.

Comment: Sorry, the `unless` is reversing my logic, I think it should be `unless !current_user.nil? && (@canvas.user_id == current_user.id)`

Comment: Nope, that's not it either. I see what you're doing though so I'll try figure it out, thanks!